# Export data from clickhouse

Tags: python, clickhouse, dbconnection

Please, suggest the best way to export data from clickhouse using python.

Right now I am using this code but have an error stating that hotsname can't be reached.

```
from clickhouse_driver import Client
client=Client(host='http://ipaddress',user='user',password='pass',port=8123)
print(client.execute('select * from table limit 5'))
```

Are there any other ways to do that?

Comment: Could you show the exact error you get?

Answer (score 1):

[clickhouse-driver](https://clickhouse-driver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)  communicates with ClickHouse over native protocol not HTTP, so:

- *host* should contain hostname or IP (not HTTP URL)
- *port* should be [9000](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/server_configuration_parameters/settings/#server_configuration_parameters-tcp_port) (or [9440](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/server_configuration_parameters/settings/#server_configuration_parameters-tcp_port-secure) for secure connection)

I would rely on the generator function [execute-iter](https://clickhouse-driver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#execute-iter) to stream an export data:

```py
from clickhouse_driver import Client

client = Client(host='localhost')

data = client.execute_iter('SELECT * FROM numbers(1 * 1000 * 1000)')
row_count = 0

for row in data:
    # do smth per row
    row_count += 1

print(f"Row count is {row_count}.")
# Row count is 1000000.
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code sample you provided,

```
from clickhouse_driver import Client
client=Client(host='http://ipaddress',user='user',password='pass',port=8123)
print(client.execute('select * from table limit 5'))
```

you put `http://ipaddress` which is not a valid hostname, if you change this to a valid hostname, it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you, actually I use the valid hostname (just put http://ipaddress as an example here)

Comment: Did you also put `http://` because that's where I'd assume it goes wrong.