# Error while connecting to clickhouse using python

Tags: python, csv, connection, clickhouse

```
from clickhouse_driver import Client
client = Client(host = 'user',port=8123)
import csv
with open('/home/user/Desktop/customer_df.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        client.execute('INSERT INTO custmer VALUES',[row])

Failed to connect to user:8123
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/clickhouse_driver/connection.py", line 342, in connect
    return self._init_connection(host, port)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/clickhouse_driver/connection.py", line 306, in _init_connection
    self.socket = self._create_socket(host, port)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/clickhouse_driver/connection.py", line 278, in _create_socket
    raise err
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/clickhouse_driver/connection.py", line 269, in _create_socket
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

How to check port of my clickhouse
and I dont know where its wrong in the code

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61301828/303298.

Answer (score 1):

`clickhouse-driver` uses the native protocol.  By default the ClickHouse server listens on port 9000 (or port 9440 for TLS), and there's not usually a reason to change it.

You can check your config.xml file for port numbers.  The setting for the TCP port is documented here https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/server-configuration-parameters/settings#server_configuration_parameters-tcp_port.

Other clients, such as JDBC or the Python `clickhouse-connect` client, use the HTTP port, which is why you often see 8123 (8443 for HTTPS).